# changing the access: from everyone to restricted user, allowing only the user that created post to be able to edit and delete

Tags: python, django

right now any user can delete and edit any post. I want only user that created the post to be able to delete or edit. I used very simple code to update and delete but the problem is it gives access to everyone....Here;s my code.

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/edit.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # Any manual settings go here
            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         return super(PostUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)



class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
     model = Post

     def get_success_url(self):
            return "/" 

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return super(PostDeleteView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

thanks in advance

Edit

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # any manual settings go here
            self.object.moderator = self.request.user
            self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 

            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))


     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization), you can check if a user has the permission on altering an object like this:

```
user.has_perm('foo.change_bar')
user.has_perm('foo.delete_bar')
```

Assuming that you have a `created_by` field in your post, you could do it like this:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    if request.user.has_perm('yourapp.delete_post') and post.created_by == request.user: 
        return super(PostDeleteView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return http.HttpForbidden()
```

If you want to reuse the logic on multiple occasions, you should consider creating a decorator based on [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) or this [Mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) for newer Django Version

Comment: thank you but I'm very confused, I edited my create view. I thought i have to write restricting decorator function on my own and work up fro there...do you mean I should put the code you provided to my create view?

Comment: yes every one can post. I googled around, I think your code is the best. hopefully has_perm method works in django 1.8 as well. by the way, for the code you provided "yourapp.delete_post", what is yourapp? do you mean the root folder? like if I have main folder and inside there, I have views.py which contains the above functions, I shoupd put main.postupdate?

Comment: if `main` is your app, then yes: `user.has_perm('main.change_post')`

Comment: I think I understand the documentation and your code, but I get an error which I think is a separate from this issue. I get KeyError at /sss/edit/
'pk'....do you know how to fix this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902395/keyerror-at-sss-edit-pk

Comment: I figured out the whole pk thing but it returns 403 page for everything even when it should edit /delete page

Answer (score 0):

You can add the checking in **dispatch** method like

```
 @method_decorator(login_required)
 def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     obj =  self.get_object()
     if not obj.moderator == self.request.user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
     return super(PostUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I replaced my dispatch with the provided code for postUpdateView, I can still edit posts other user created