# KeyError at /sss/edit/ 'pk'

Tags: python, django

Hello I get this error:

```
KeyError at /sss/edit/
'pk'
```

I know `KeyError` mean there's no key in a dict but I don't understand why it's giving me this error here.

Here's my code:

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/edit.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # Any manual settings go here
            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        if request.user.has_perm('main.change_post') and post.created_by == request.user:
            return super(PostUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return http.HttpForbidden()
```

I get error from `post=Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])`

I have this model as well

```
class Post(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the `pk` if you have defined it in your urls.py like this:

```
url(r'^sss/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', PostUpdateView.as_view())
```

Comment: oh that's why...what if I'm using slug  url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
then I should change pk=kwargs[pk] to slug=slug right?

Comment: rather to `slug=kwargs['slug']`. This only works if slugs are unique, because you are calling `get` on the Post-Object.

Comment: I did  url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
then now it gives me 404 page not found error

Comment: what is the url you called?

Comment: I got the url thing figured it out but the default permission thing does not work, it gives me 403 page even when it should give edit page

Comment: does your PostModel have a `created_by` field?

Comment: sorry for a late response, I have this moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)

Comment: Then you need to change `post.created_by` to `post.moderator`

Comment: Thanks Remi, I understand the code but I keep get 403error....not sure why I double checked everything....

Comment: Which one is false? has_perm or the user check? Did you grant the permissions to the user in the admin? Did you try to debug? If the user check returns false, debug both values or the ids...

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not a very good coder, I googled and reviewed the code but this seems right and yet when I go into edit url I get forbidden access. In my admin page I only have 
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = ('title', 'category')

admin.site.register(Post, PageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category)

Comment: I can offer you to chat in about 2 hours? This is getting too much for the comments...

Comment: yeah sure then I would be super grateful